# How to add query as string to another query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to have a generated query:

```
SELECT @numberOfRecords = COUNT(*) FROM Car WHERE CarId not in (Select CarId from CarData)
```

At the moment I have :

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(255)
SET @sql='Select CarId from CarData'

DECLARE @numberOfRecords BIGINT
SELECT @numberOfRecords = COUNT(*) FROM Car WHERE CarId not in (@sql)
```

I was trying other various combinations, like `'('` nut it doesn't work.
What I need to change to have it working?

Comment: I added more details to my answer, hopefully this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called dynamic sql, there is numerous articles about it, you'll need to use sp_executesql if you are using SQL Server

there is an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) for something similar to what you are trying to do

your solution should look something like this

```
DECLARE @carIdSql        NVARCHAR(255),
        @sql             NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @numberOfRecords BIGINT

SET @carIdSql='Select CarId from CarData';

SET @sql =
N'SELECT @numberOfRecordsOUT = COUNT(*) 
  FROM Car WHERE CarId not in (' + @carIdSql + ')'

SET @ParamDefinition = '@numberOfRecordsOUT BIGINT OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql
  @sql,
  @ParamDefinition,
  @numberOfRecordsOUT = @numberOfRecords OUTPUT;

SELECT @numberOfRecords
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

```
DECLARE
@numberOfRecords       INT ,
@VariableSQL NVARCHAR(255),
@SQLStmt     NVARCHAR(255),
@paramtype   NVARCHAR(100)

SET @VariableSQL = 'Select CarId from CarData'

SET @SQLStmt = 'SELECT @counter = COUNT(1) FROM Car WHERE CarId NOT IN (' + @variablesql + ')'

SET @ParamType = '@counter int output'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStmt, @paramtype, @Counter = @numberOfRecords OUTPUT
PRINT @numberOfRecords
```

Comment: You've completely missed what they are trying to do (plug in a dynamic `not in` sub query) They need dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: I want you to know,that it wasn't me

Comment: Thank you, I apparently didn't read the subject line, was just focused on what I saw wrong with the query. I have updated the answer with a working example that will solve the question.

Comment: @user278618: it would have been alright if it was you because as martin smith pointed out, I missed the actual request. I have updated my answer with a working solution.